# How to Run windows phone 7.1 Emulator on Windows8

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I'm having some problems with WindowsPhone 7.1 Emulator on Window 8 CTP; it looks like the emulator has some dependencies from OS version.

When I attempt to deploy it in Visual Studio, I receive the following error:

**Error 1   Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments. 0  0**

I know that the CTP version of Win8 is not the best os for development now, but this question is interesting for me and our user group.

**Online help message:**

> Windows Phone Emulator has been blocked from running because it might prevent your computer from starting correctly in the future.
>
> Your version of Windows Phone Emulator isn't compatible with this version of Windows.
>
> For information about possible solutions to this problem, go online to the following Knowledge Base (KB) article:
>
> Click to go online to the Microsoft website for the KB article
>   Which version of Windows am I using?
>
> You are using Windows 8.

Comment: Maybe you should try to change some environment variables responsible for win version or you can even try to hook some WinAPI, but I think it's not worth it. Probably MS just limited it and most likely they have some reasons for it.

Comment: The emulator just isn't supported on Win 8 as of yet.

Comment: have you tried with a device?

Answer (score 6):

It didn't work for me but some people said to worked for them 
Now you can download WP 7.1.1 SDK that run on windows 8 :)
Here is the link
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29233

Comment: I tested this on Windows 8 Consumer Preview x64 and it works. I installed SDK 7.1 first, got some error that XNA Game Studio 4.0 couldn't be installed but then I installed SDK 7.1.1 and emulator works great. I have Visual Studio 11 Beta as the only VS installed btw. It is also described in this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/28/install-windows-phone-sdk-7-1-7-11-on-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx

Comment: Worked for me also. Steps to install:
1) Install VS 2011 
2) Install Windows Phone SDK 7.1 - will also install VS 2010 (Ignore XNA errors)
3) Update Windows Phone SDK (7.1.1)

Comment: Yes! I had SDK 7.1 installed and upgraded Win 7 to Win 8.  I got a compatibility error.  Installed 7.1.1 SDK and all is well.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you quoted,

> Your version of Windows Phone Emulator isn't compatible with this version of Windows.

It seems to me that all you can do is wait for an update, or (somehow) find the emulator's source code and try to recompile it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 32-bit version of Windows 8, you can safely run the Windows Phone 7.1 emulator in compatibility mode. Right click on the executable and click the compatibility tab. Check the 'Run the program in compatibility mode for' checkbox and select "Windows 7" from the list. Click Apply and away you go.

Answer (score 1):

try install Windows phone sdk 7.1.1 -> http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29233
but mostly people got error install when installing xna, before you install windows phone sdk you must install gwlivesetup from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5549. After that you must install or reinstall your WP SDK. Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator just isn't supported on Win 8 as of yet.

What ever you do DO NOT try running the emulator with Administrative priviledges or you will see just how incompatible the emualtor is as you will get to see the new "chic" looking Windows 8 Blue screen of death.

There is definately a problem with the virual host used to run the emulator itself as other virtual solutions are still able to work like Virtual Box.
You can run the emualtor in a limited fashion using Virtualbox on a Win 8 machine but you will have no access to the toolbox or be able to run XNA

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know. It is really incompatible with Win8 due to the lack of some APIs in the new OS. It will be update in the future.

You can still develop using a real WP7 device if you have one, to debug and test our applications just fine in Win8.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed VS2011 for windows phone in win 8 like this.

1. Update .Net framework to version 3.5
2. Insall [Games for Windows Marketplace Client Setup](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/live/pc/downloadclient) for the xna to work in win 8
3. Install Visual studio 2011.
4. Install a [patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29233) for VS2011 to work with win8

And voila! :)